# Dependent or Independent

Tags: statistical-significance, independence, descriptive-statistics

Suppose we have a function $y=x^2+\epsilon$ where the noise term $\epsilon$ is iid with mean $0$, from this function we sample two tuples
$$(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)$$
Assume that to get these tuples we randomly sample an $x$ and then plug in $y=f(x)=x^2$.

$x_1$ and $x_2$ are independent since they are sampled randomly. Also, $y_1$ and $y_2$ are also independent due to correspondence with the random $x$.

What about the tuples $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)$ can we say they are independent ? They obviously come from the same underlying function so they should have some dependence or commonalities, for example $E(y|x)=x^2$.

How can we write there dependence structure if indeed they are dependent ?

Answer (score 0):

The two *bivariate* random variables $\vec A = (X_1, Y_1)$ and 
$\vec B = (X_2, Y_2)$
are *independent* and thus their *joint* CDF factors as
$$F_{\vec A, \vec B}\left(\vec x,\vec y\right) = F_{\vec A, \vec B}(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2)
=F_{\vec A}\left(\vec a\right)F_{\vec B}\left(\vec b\right)
= F_{\vec A}(x_1,y_1)F_{\vec B}(x_2,y_2)$$
but the individual variables comprising $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ are *not* independent. Specifically,
$$F_{\vec A}(x_1,y_1) = F_{X_1,Y_1}(x_1,y_1)
\neq F_{X_1}(x_1)F_{Y_1}(y_1)\\
F_{\vec B}(x_2,y_2) = F_{X_2,Y_2}(x_2,y_2)
\neq F_{X_2}(x_2)F_{Y_2}(y_2)
$$